# os.path.isfile is not working with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to create a code that would help me to copy similar jpg files.So it was important to me to know whether the files exist or not.

For that I wrote down the following code:

```
from os import path
import shutil



oldfile = input("Which file do you want to copy? write that in numbers : ")
fadress = input("What is your file adress : ")
newfadress = input("Where do you want to copy your file : ")

f_num2 = oldfile.split('-')


for each_num in f_num2:
      print(each_num)
      newname = '_DSC{}.JPG'.format(each_num)
      new2 = 'DSC_{}.JPG'.format(each_num)
      if path.isfile(fadress + '\\' + newname):
          shutil.copy(fadress + '\\' + newname, newfadress)
          print(newname)
      elif path.isfile(fadress + '\\' + new2):
          shutil.copy(fadress + '\\' + new2, newfadress)
          print(new2)
```

It's working before the if statements.But it seems that the if statements are not taking the output of os.path.isfile function.What should I do to make this code work?

Comment: The `path.isfile` function works like a charm. Your path is probably wrong. I suggest that you print out `fadress + '\\' + newname` to see if it really is what you're expecting.

Comment: try `path.isfile(path.join(fadress.strip(), newname))`

Comment: Can you give us any output for debugging? add an else with `print fadress + '\\' + newname` and `print path.isfile(fadress + '\\' + newname)`

Comment: To be a proper [mcve], this would *create* the file (so we know it really exists) before showing that the code branches as if it did not. Otherwise, it requires setup on the machine where it's being run before it can be tested, making it neither **C**omplete nor **V**erifiable.

Comment: (Removing the user input and using hardcoded values or letting Python generate a filename with the tempfile module would also be steps towards being **M**inimal).

Answer (score 1):

can you strip `fadress` before using it and join paths using `path.join`?

```
path.isfile(path.join(fadress.strip(), newname))
```

(or) strip it while reading `fadress` itself?

```
fadress = input("What is your file adress : ").strip()
```

Comment: yup trailing new line from STDIN might be the issue